# how to use window.history.replaceState()....?

Tags: jquery, html, browser-history

i am trying to change the content in url bar. for now i am trying to just send some url to the url bar using replace state. I am calling this on a click of a button. 
The browser console doesnot show any kind of error but url is not being displayed.i would prefer using Jquery.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
        <script>
           $(document).ready(function() { 

        $("#123").click(function(){
        alert("in submit");
        window.history.replaceState({foo: 'bar'}, 'Nice URL Title', '/nice_url');        
                }); 
            </script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="outer">
    <p>This is My Div</p>
    <button id="123" type="button" >click me</button>
    </div>


    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Do you see the alert on click?

Comment: yes. I do. If i place alert below the window.history.replaceState()  .. then i don't see it. But a error doesn't show up either.

Comment: What browser do you use? Can you test your replaceState in a console?

Comment: i am using chrome (latest version). what do you mean by testing replaceState in a console?  the console of chorme shows me now error or anything if that is what your asking.

Comment: Just type in the console and see if this works or gives any error: window.history.replaceState({foo: 'bar'}, 'Nice URL Title', '/nice_url')

Comment: No error either? Did you try incognito mode or some other browser (Firefox, Safari)?

Comment: yeah tried them to same problem. No error & also no o/p .   Are you getting otherwise when you tried ?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome & Safari on this stackoverflow page. Are you testing on a local file? That can be a problem.